# How to solve 'pcl/features/board.h' not found?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow [pcl recognition](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php#correspondence-grouping).

My [src](http://pastebin.com/SQtGLqjC).

When I rosmake ([full msg](http://pastebin.com/jr8YSvWU)),it shows:

```
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:6:32: 嚴重錯誤： pcl/features/board.h：沒有此一檔案或目錄
    編譯插斷。
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
```

Sorry for my chinese output.

I failed to change to english version output by locale.

I try to run:

```
  export LANG=en_US
  export LC_MESSAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

How to fix the pcl header not found?

Thank you~

=============================================

I try to download perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable.

And I passed the rosmake.

If my manifest change to :

```
  <package>
    <description brief="pcl_3d_recognition">
  
       pcl_3d_recognition
  
    </description>
    <author>ROSfuerte</author>
    <license>BSD</license>
    <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
    <url>http://ros.org/wiki/pcl_3d_recognition</url>
    <depend package="roscpp"/>
    <depend package="pcl16"/>
    <depend package="pcl16_ros"/>
  
  </package>
```

It will show the different error,but seems become very strange. Because even the basic header of first line(pcl/io/pcd_io.h) that also couldn't find.

The rosmake msg is [(full msg)](http://pastebin.com/GRe5DiU5):

```
    [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:1:27: 嚴重錯誤： pcl/io/pcd_io.h：沒有此一檔案或目錄
    編譯插斷。
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
```

If I change manifest to

```
  <package>
    <description brief="pcl_3d_recognition">
  
       pcl_3d_recognition
  
    </description>
    <author>ROSfuerte</author>
    <license>BSD</license>
    <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
    <url>http://ros.org/wiki/pcl_3d_recognition</url>
    <depend package="roscpp"/>
    <depend package="pcl"/>
    <depend package="pcl_ros"/>
    <depend package="pcl16"/>
    <depend package="pcl16_ros"/>
  
  </package>
```

It just show the first sitation of my problem I post in the beginning.

How to fix it?

Thank you~

==========================================

I only change the header to

```
  #include <pcl16/io/pcd_io.h>
  #include <pcl16/point_cloud.h>
  #include <pcl16/correspondence.h>
  #include <pcl16/features/normal_3d_omp.h>
  #include <pcl16/features/shot_omp.h>
  #include <pcl16/features/board.h>
  #include <pcl16/keypoints/uniform_sampling.h>
  #include <pcl16/recognition/cg/hough_3d.h>
  #include <pcl16/recognition/cg/geometric_consistency.h>
  #include <pcl16/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
  #include <pcl16/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
  #include <pcl16/kdtree/impl/kdtree_flann.hpp>
  #include <pcl16/common/transforms.h>
  #include <pcl16/console/parse.h>
```

But when I rosmake, it shows [(full msg)](http://pastebin.com/imPg2Mss):

```
    [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o
    In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/point_representation.h:42:0,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/kdtree/kdtree.h:46,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/search/kdtree.h:43,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/search/pcl_search.h:44,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/features/impl/feature.hpp:43,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/features/feature.h:502,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/features/normal_3d.h:43,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/features/normal_3d_omp.h:43,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:4:
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/point_types.h:56:0: 警告： ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/point_representation.h:42:0,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/kdtree/kdtree.h:46,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/search/kdtree.h:43,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/search/pcl_search.h:44,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/features/impl/feature.hpp:43,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/features/feature.h:502,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/features/normal_3d.h:43,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/features/normal_3d_omp.h:43,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:4:
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/include/pcl-1.6/pcl16/point_types.h:590:0: 警告： ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:6:34: 嚴重錯誤： pcl16/features/board.h：沒有此一檔案或目錄
    編譯插斷。
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

=============================================

I have tried pcl17.

When I rosmake it shows that vtkAppendPolyData.h not found.[(the full msg)](http://pastebin.com/NXCVRaYT)

```
    [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o
    In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/common/impl/io.hpp:45:0,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/common/io.h:488,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/file_io.h:42,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/pcd_io.h:44,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:1:
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/point_types.h:56:0: 警告： ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/common/impl/io.hpp:45:0,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/common/io.h:488,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/file_io.h:42,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/pcd_io.h:44,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:1:
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/point_types.h:636:0: 警告： ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/visualization/common/common.h:40:0,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h:50,
                     from /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/src/correspondence_grouping.cpp:10:
    /home/sam/code/ros/pcl/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/visualization/vtk.h:51:31: 嚴重錯誤： vtkAppendPolyData.h：沒有此一檔案或目錄
    編譯插斷。
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/src/correspondence_grouping.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/correspondence_grouping.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/pcl/pcl_3d_recognition/build'
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

How to solve it?

Should I post this on another thread?

And does it means that the original problem (pcl/features/board.h) is solved?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44136/how-to-solve-%27pcl/features/board.h%27-not-found?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-19**:
According to this: http://www.pcl-users.org/3d-Object-Recognition-td3974058.html you need experimental version of pcl. So see also http://answers.ros.org/question/36837/how-to-use-current-experimental-pcl-together-with-ros-fuerte/

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-20**:
I have rosmake it success. But when I add dependency pcl16 and pcl16_ros, it still say the same problem. What to do next? Thank you~

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-20**:
Please either remove all non-erroneous output from your question or use such services as [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for providing full log and source files. The text of you question is a way too long now, which makes it very difficult to read.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-23**:
Yes, I believe it is another problem. Most probably you need to install development version of VTK, if under Ubuntu try something like `sudo apt-get vtk-dev`. However it is not ROS-related question, so you have to ask it on PCL forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this [post](http://www.pcl-users.org/3d-Object-Recognition-td3974058.html) you need experimental version of pcl. So see also http://answers.ros.org/question/36837/how-to-use-current-experimental-pcl-together-with-ros-fuerte/

---

*EDIT #1 (THIS ONE IS NOT NECESSARY)*

<strike>I think you have to use [this](http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/) repository. Once you check the code out replace `SVN_URL` variable in `perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/Makefile` like:</strike>

```
SVN_URL = http://svn.pointclouds.org/pcl/trunk
```

This will checkout *experimental* `pcl` version (see relevant section [here](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/source.html)) during `rosmake` and the mentioned `Makefile` will put it in `pcl16` namespace.

### Hope it helps.

EDIT#2 (*modified*)

Everything of experimental `pcl` not only in a different namespace, but also all the headers in different root folder, i.e. `pcl17`. That is to make both versions of `pcl` (standard and experimental) available to user.

Thus, you should change all includes in you example code from

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
```

to

```
#include <pcl17/io/pcd_io.h>
```

as stated in section [Integration with ROS](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/).

Sorry for confusion, I should have given you this one at the beginning.

---

EDIT #3

Checkout code from [same repository](http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/) and do everything you did before, but for **`pcl17`** instead of `pcl16`. **`pcl17`** already has a correct `SVN_URL` in the Makefile to checkout experimental code.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-20**:
Is that equal to perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-20**:
I'm not sure, but if pcl16/Makefile is similar to [this one](http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl16/Makefile), then probably yes.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-20**:
I have edit my original post. What can I do next? Thank you~

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-20**:
I have changed headers and edit my original post. What can I do next? Thank you~

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-20**:
It is not necessary to post comments here as all interested users will receive notification and will answer if they can.

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-06-14**:
I found I linked but it seems eigen lib is missing at compilaton.